# Why do .NET 6 Office Interop Dynamic References No Longer Work

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic, interop, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading a WPF C# project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6 - Happily, .NET 6 has support for Word and Excel Office Interop.  However, I've found that where before I was able to reference things like Excel Ranges and Range properties such as Font, Interior, etc. without casting to Range, now I do.  So,

```
var cell = xlWs.Cells[r, c];
cell.Interior.Color = rowColor;
```

now has to be coded:

```
Range cell = ((Range)xlWs.Cells[r, c]);
cell.Interior.Color = rowColor;
```

Not the end of the world, but is forcing me to make a few hundred changes I'd rather not have to make.  Is there any way around this?  Has anybody else migrated older Interop code to .NET 6 yet?

Thanks.